# Upload File in Web Service URL with Token using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

While file post to the Rest service url getting stuck as below code

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", Tokenvalue);
System.Net.Http.HttpContent content1 = new StringContent(UploadDocRequest, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");
HttpResponseMessage messge1 = client.PostAsync(url , content1).Result;
```

> Error: Forbidden some time Not Found.

Can u Please help me any one.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the target api to see if it is CSRF protected or not?

Comment: Yes, I Have access to code

Comment: Actually in access code                                                                                        
           var file = $('#uploadfile')[0];
            formData.append('file', file.files[0]);   for httpContent what should have pass the data.

Comment: Please add the complete target api code together with its attributes and any possible concrete authorization to the question.